# Task ContinueWith calls a method with another task

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, task-parallel-library

In a winforms application I have a method that downloads a file decompress a ZIP file. In order for it to not freeze my UI I ran the decompress command from within a task.

When the decompression task calls the ContinueWith to continue and inside that ContinueWith I call another method, which then continues my application logic. One of the methods in my logic also needs to run in a task. The problem is that when I run that method with the second task it doesn't seem like it's running in a task and my app freezes.

This is the code:

```
Task T = new Task(() =>
{
    System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(
        Path.Combine(_tempDirectory, "update.zip"),
        Path.Combine(_tempDirectory, "update"));
});

Task T2 = T.ContinueWith((previosTask) =>
{
    continueUpdate();
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

The continue method then has some logic and calls another method:

```
private void continueUpdate()
{
    // some logic
    copyTargetFiles();
}

private void copyTargetFiles()
{
    Task T = new Task(() =>
    {
            string backupPath = Path.Combine(_tempDirectory, "Backup\\Files");
            Directory.CreateDirectory(backupPath);

            string sourceFolder = Shared.GetRegistryKey("Folder");
            Infrastructure.Shared.CopyDirectory(sourceFolder, backupPath);
    });
    T.Start();
}
```

When it gets to copyTargetFiles the application freezes.

any suggestions? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code that you omited is highly relevant to your problem.  The code that you have provided will *not* block the UI thread.  Whatever you have in `// some logic` is what is blocking the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

You are blocking your UI thread by continuing on a specific scheduler.

```
TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
```

By specifying a specific scheduler context, all nested tasks (regardless of being children) will use that schedule context by default. In your code, this results in the `Task` started in `copyTargetFiles` being run on the UI thread. Debug it and see for yourself!

You should remove the 2nd parameter of `ContinueWith` (the one quoted above).

Edit: try this additional fix

```
private Task copyTargetFiles()
{
    Task T = new Task(() =>
    {
            string backupPath = Path.Combine(_tempDirectory, "Backup\\Files");
            Directory.CreateDirectory(backupPath);

            string sourceFolder = Shared.GetRegistryKey("Folder");
            Infrastructure.Shared.CopyDirectory(sourceFolder, backupPath);
    });
    T.Start(TaskScheduler.Default); //jumps back to the default, unrestricted scheduler context for the file copying

    return T;
}
```

Comment: After removing that parameter it throw an exception when trying to update a UI element inside continueUpdate()

Comment: @developer82 Yes, continuations run after the task is completed, either normally or exceptionally.

Comment: @developer82 I'm afraid i can't tell you what the problem is with your UI access as you have omitted that code (`//some logic`?). I've put some more edits in.

Answer (score 0):

This is the well known behavior, `Task.Factory.StartNew` and `Task.Start` are evils. They uses `TaskScheduler.Current` meaning any tasks started from them will be scheduled in its parent scheduler.

In your case `copyTargetFiles` is called from UI, when it starts a new `Task` that is also scheduled in UI only.

How to fix:

Use `Task.Run` which uses `TaskScheduler.Default` which points to ThreadPool.

```
Task t = Task.Run(() =>
{
        string backupPath = Path.Combine(_tempDirectory, "Backup\\Files");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(backupPath);

        string sourceFolder = Shared.GetRegistryKey("Folder");
        Infrastructure.Shared.CopyDirectory(sourceFolder, backupPath);
});
```

I recommend you to read [Task.Factory.StartNew is Dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), StephenCleary explains it very well.